# can not receive notification of change, key value observing, KVO model-IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, objective-c-category

Im registering an observer for on of my class named myClassA ( subclass of uiview ) from one of my class named UIScrollView(Sample)( a category for uiscroll view )

```
@implementation UIScrollView (myClass)
    // Register an observer       
    - (void)registerAsObserver {        
         [self addObserver:[self getMyClassA] forKeyPath:@"notification" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
```

In myClassA

```
@implementation myClassA

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization goes here        
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Receive notification of change 
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    CGPoint newPoint    =   [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];

    if ( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"notification"] ) {
        [self doSomething:newPoint];

    }

}
```

However, it seems to be that myClassA is not receiving any notification from `UIScrollView(myClass)`. After google it, i found out that the reason is the keyword ***forKeyPath***. If i change it to `contentOffset`, everything works like charm.

Did a quick research at [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) but still dont understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Apple's basic documentation on KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html):

> With KVO, one object can observe any *properties* of another object

Well, UIScrollView has a `contentOffset` property. So it is *key value coding compliant* for `contentOffset`. So you can observe changes to that property, and that is what you are asking to do if you set the key path to `contentOffset`.

UIScrollView has no `notification` property, so its `notification` property can never change, so there is nothing to observe if you set the key path to `notification`.

Here's the explanation from my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_key_value_observing